# Recursion && given stack memory challenge

Tags: c, recursion, memory-management, software-design, recursive-backtracking

I studied recursion on c programming and I have one concern about stack memory handling on recursive calls while recursive function is getting executed. specifically how things are done on stack memory ..

assume given this recursive function as following :

```
void recursion(int num) {


    if (num == 1 || num < 1 )
     {
       return ;
      }
     recursion(num/10);
}
```

assume num given as input 100 to the function, as well as we have stack
memory given from 0 - 100 bytes , meaning that there is given implicitly integer array where its size from index 0 to 100. lets say given stackmemory[100] where recursion function work upon it

Now my concern is how I can by recursive calls keep tracking that I didnt arrive the maximum of stack memory? didnt reach stackover flow ..
meaning how can I be sure that on the next recursive call that there is enough stack memory for next recursive call and if there is no sufficient space left on stack memory
then recursion shall stop.

How I can keep tracking that? I was thinking about pointers to save/store some pointers aside and ampersend "&" related somehow to tackle that issue.

any idea or any help to tackle this issue? by the way the original function (given above recursion function) can be edited and to add any other additional functions ..

Thanks.

```
void recursion(int num) {


    if (num == 1 || num < 1 )
     {
       return ;
      }
     recursion(num/10);
}
```

Comment: "How can I be sure that on the next..." basically, you cannot. There is no mechanism for you to determine available space on the stack at runtime.

Comment: @Gerhardh but its given as an assumption that you have stackmemory with size 100 Bytes. so its just an example ... assume u have the stackmemroy size array which is 100 integer elements .. so how you can validate on the next recursive call you have not reached the limit of stack?

Comment: Again: You cannot. You would need to know, how much of that stack you consume per call. You would need to know how much of these 100 integers are already in use. Also, depending on the CPU architecture, you might need to take all possible interrupts into account that might also use your stack. C does not provide a mechanism for any of that. See Lundin's answer.

Comment: I understand @Gerhardh , so how by assembly we can do that?

Answer (score 1):

> assume num given as input 100 to the function, as well as we have stack memory given from 0 - 100 bytes

That's not making any sense. In your division algorithm, the value 100 has nothing to do with the amount of stack used. What's stacked (as per "calling convention") is the return address and the state of various registers depending on target, and in addition parameters may get stacked as well. An `int` parameter would then take up 4 bytes per call.

Your function here will have n=100, then n=10 and finally n=1, so 3 function calls. Depending on target, you might end up stacking something like (roughly) 4 to 16 bytes per call.

There is no "implicit integer array of size 100".

Also please note that recursion in the best case scenario can get optimized out. For example if we introduce a side effect to your function (so that it won't get 100% optimized out, which it currently will) then at least the latest gcc/x86 manages to remove the recursive call and replace it with a loop. (So-called tail call optimization.) https://godbolt.org/z/eP1s6E9Th Note that the assembly doesn't contain any `call recursion` instructions. This whole thing might get inlined into the caller code.

In fact this particular example was so trivial so that when including a caller code, it didn't even inline the function but replaced the whole thing with 3 printf statements printing 100, 10 and 1 respectively: https://godbolt.org/z/cGjaEEnfT

For more complex code the compiler might not be able to optimize it and that's when stack overflows and needlessly slow execution happen.

> Now my concern is how I can by recursive calls keep tracking that I didnt arrive the maximum of stack memory?

You can't do that trivially. It would involve inline assembler that access the stack pointer before the first call, then check it inside each recursive call. The potential for stack overflow is one of the main reasons why recursion in C is regarded as dangerous and bad practice.

It *might* be possible to achieve in C through some very hackish means, such as dissecting the contents of a `jmp_buf` variable, then using `setjmp`/`longjmp` as a fail safe. Not something I'd recommend.

> any idea or any help to tackle this issue?

Yes - don't use recursion. In some 99% of all algorithms you can come up with, recursion is almost certainly the wrong solution. Not only because it is dangerous, but also because it is slow and often hard to read.

Comment: it's only an example for more understandings side, again lets say you have only stackmemory[100] and someone tells you how u can keep tracking the stackmemory size / consumption which you will not actually call the next recursive function if no memory size, so what I was thinking about is on pointers and save the pointer of each recursive function where it allocates memory on stack so we already know that stackmemory is 100 so the ( initial offset + 100 ) is the maximal limit .. got my point?

Comment: lets stack from basics , per each call how many stacking memory it could be? you said " Depending on target, you might end up stacking something like (roughly) 4 to 16 bytes per call. " , how I can calculate stacking memory per each recursive call would be allocated? its depend on how many data and codes found on the function itself yes?

Comment: @Dave_hmster The problem is that you can't even access the sp from C, hence the need for inline assembler or dirty hacks. Or if you are dead certain of the calling convention, you can probably predict the amount of stack use statically before the program is launched.

Comment: what Im talking about @Lundin is what's called " Limit the depth
 " , by this method we can avoid stackover flow ..

Comment: Most modern optimising compilers would recognise the tail recursion in your example and eliminate it entirely. They would even work for something more challenging like the canonical and potentially dangerous recursive definition of factorial as num*recursion(num-1). [Ackermann's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) is the one to try and compute if you really want to test out overflowing the stack. First discovered example of a total computable function that isn't primitive recursive. It gets big very very quickly!!!

Comment: @MartinBrown But just add a `printf("%d", n)` at the end of the function and they fail to optimize it. So it doesn't take much at all to trip the optimizer.

Comment: How I can actually save the pointer of the called function on c programming? like assume Im calling same function for first time so it's f1() , how I can save the function pointer itself?

Comment: @Dave_hmster, one ordinarily limits recursion depth by choosing good algorithms and implementing them appropriately.  In *any* language that supports recursion, not just C.  Overall, your hypothetical doesn't make much real-world sense because one ordinarily does not know how much stack is available overall, or how much is free.  And if you run out of stack before reaching the bottom of the recursion then there usually is not much recourse other than to abort the program, which is typically what will happen anyway if you do nothing.